# How to make a list for array elements?

Tags: c

I need to make a list for every new elements in the array. For example I type in (1,2,3,4,5) then (6,7,8,9,10) I need both to show in (void view). I hope you understand

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 5
int a[MAX];
int x, s;

void view() {
    for(x = 0; x < MAX; x++) {
        printf("%d. %d" , s, a[x]);
    }
}
int main() {
    int run=1;
    while(run) {
        char choice;
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        if(choice=='e') {
              for(x=0; x<MAX; x++) {
                  printf("\n");
                  printf("\tEnter value: ");
                  scanf("%d", &a[x]);
              }
        }
        else if(choice=='v') {
            view(); 
         }      
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? How to *read* it or how to *print* it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes but every time i print new elements the old ones disappear. As I said I need kind of list to keep the old prints

Comment: Well then, you need a bigger array.  Either over-declare the array to an acceptable size, eg [65536], or use malloc/realloc to grow a dynamically-allocated array.

Comment: @MartinJames it's a school homework it shouldn't be too complicated and the size of the array has to be 5.

Comment: Then you cannot achieve what you seem to want without involving even more added complications, eg. files.  If the array size is 5, it can store 5 elements, that's it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a home work service.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 if this website isn't for educational purposes then what is it for? If you don't want to help fine but keep your attitude back low

Comment: `this website isn't for educational purposes then what is it for?` to help with programming problems. People who have shown some effort (this couple of lines of code is not considered as an effort) and have done all the exercises from the beginners C book. Where is your effort?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to store your previous input in a buffer, say a matrix of size N*Max where N is maximum number of inputs one can take before printing them out and Max is a number of integers for each input time.

`

```
#define Max 5  
#define N 10  
int a[N][MAX];  

void view(int counter){
   for(int i=0;i<=counter;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<MAX;j++){
           printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
           }
        printf("\n");   
        }
    }

void main(){

while(1){
    int counter = 0;
    char choice;
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    if(choice=='e'){
        for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
            printf("Enter A no\n");
            scanf("%d",&a[counter][i]);
        }
        counter++;
    }
    else if(choice =='v')
        view(counter);

}
}
```

`

Comment: `void main()` Really?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a 2D-array, consisting of, let's say, `MAXRUN` rows and `MAX` columns. Your code seems already to be prepared for this, as you seem to have introduced `s` for counting the rows entered. The following code should work for you; hope it helps:

```
#define MAX 5
#define MAXRUN 5
int a[MAXRUN][MAX];
int x, s;

void view() {
    for (int r = 0; r < s; r++) {
        printf("\n%d. run:", r+1);
        for(x = 0; x < MAX; x++) {
            printf("%d ", a[r][x]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    s=0;
    while(s < MAXRUN) {
        char choice;
        printf("\nchoose (e)nter or (v)iew:");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        if(choice=='e') {
            for(x=0; x<MAX; x++) {
                printf("Enter value: ");
                scanf("%d", &a[s][x]);
            }
            s++;
        }
        else if(choice=='v') {
            view();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a 2-dimensional array. A 1-dimensional looks something like this:

```
arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

and a 2-dimensional array looks like this:

```
arr[5][2]={ {1,2,3,4,5}
            {6,7,8,9,10} };
```

just use this code insted of yours:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROW 5
#define COL 5
int a[ROW][COL];

void view() {
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < ROW; x++) {
        for(j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            printf("%d" , a[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
int main() {
    int run=1,i,j;
    while(run) {
        char choice;
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        if(choice=='e') {
              for(i=0; i<ROW; i++) {
                  printf("\nList of elements for array %d:",i);
                  for(j=0; j<COL; j++) {
                      printf("\n");
                      printf("\tEnter value: ");
                      scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
                  }
              }
        }
        else if(choice=='v') {
            view(); 
         }      
    }
}
```

This will take upto 5 1-dimensional arrays. if you need more just increase the value of COL